# Can Redis and ElasticSearch exist on the same server

Tags: linux, database, elasticsearch, redis

Well my question might be easy to answer but I'm really curious and would like to know if anyone has ever done it. For my graduation project I am working on research into Databases in a couple of scenarios  I tested them on a Linux VM (Ubuntu) separately but on the same machine (I stop one and start the other). After some research Redis and ElasticSearch came out as the best ones in two diverent scenarios. After that I tried to run them at the same time but they seem to influence each other (Redis works ElasticSearch does not).

Now my question is: Is it possible to run them both on the same machine? If so how would that work?

Comment: Elasticsearch and Redis are both memory hungry. It could be what is giving you problems. The other thing to consider is thep port being used. Is it different ports?

Comment: Well I guess that is it because their running on a VM with enough memory to run a single database program so I guess running to is taking to much. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use both on the same system at work, and it's fine as long as there's enough memory available for both. By default the use different ports (6379 vs 9200), so there's no problem there.

Comment: That is it I guess because of the Virtual Machine there might be to little memory. Good to know that on an actual server it can run. Tank you!